# Windows 2003 reboot times

Tags: windows-server-2003

How would I determine the times and dates a windows 2003 server was rebooted over the last 2 months.

What would I be looking for in the logs.

Thanks

JoeOD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event Log ID 6009 is logged at every boot. There are additional startup ID's to indicate whether the previous shutdown was clean (6006) or not (6008) and that the eventlog service had been started (6005).

Comment: User32 helps as well, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Event 6009 in the System log is normally a pretty good indication, assuming that the logs haven't been cleared or recycled in the time period in question.